# can't build OpenCV + GStreamer correctly (MinGW, Windows)

Tags: opencv, mingw, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to run test pipeline:

```
 cv::VideoCapture cap = cv::VideoCapture(" autovideosrc ! videoconvert ! appsink0 ", cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

But it doesn't start and return next debug info (see below). I compiled opencv using mingw32 7.3.0. Version of Gstreamer is also 32bit. What can be wrong?
win7, mingw 7.3.0, opencv 4.1.0, gstreamer 1.16.0

```
    0:00:00.040498363  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:793:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: module_open failed: 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdecklink.dll': РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅР° СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅР°СЏ РїСЂРѕС†РµРґСѓСЂР°.

        (untitled2.exe:6904): GStreamer-WARNING **: 02:29:33.412: Failed to load plugin 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdecklink.dll': 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdecklink.dll': 
The specified procedure was not found.
        0:00:00.061620856  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:793:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: module_open failed: 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopenh264.dll': РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅР° СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅР°СЏ РїСЂРѕС†РµРґСѓСЂР°.

        (untitled2.exe:6904): GStreamer-WARNING **: 02:29:33.432: Failed to load plugin 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopenh264.dll': 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopenh264.dll': 
The specified procedure was not found.
        0:00:00.072668621  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:793:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: module_open failed: 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsoundtouch.dll': РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅР° СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅР°СЏ РїСЂРѕС†РµРґСѓСЂР°.

        (untitled2.exe:6904): GStreamer-WARNING **: 02:29:33.442: Failed to load plugin 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsoundtouch.dll': 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsoundtouch.dll': 
The specified procedure was not found.
        0:00:00.088487674  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:793:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: module_open failed: 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsrt.dll': РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅР° СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅР°СЏ РїСЂРѕС†РµРґСѓСЂР°.

        (untitled2.exe:6904): GStreamer-WARNING **: 02:29:33.465: Failed to load plugin 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsrt.dll': 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsrt.dll': 
The specified procedure was not found.
        0:00:00.089972159  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:793:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: module_open failed: 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsttaglib.dll': РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅР° СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅР°СЏ РїСЂРѕС†РµРґСѓСЂР°.

        (untitled2.exe:6904): GStreamer-WARNING **: 02:29:33.465: Failed to load plugin 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsttaglib.dll': 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsttaglib.dll': 
The specified procedure was not found.
        0:00:00.097988553  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN      GST_PLUGIN_LOADING gstplugin.c:793:_priv_gst_plugin_load_file_for_registry: module_open failed: 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstwebrtcdsp.dll': РќРµ РЅР°Р№РґРµРЅР° СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅР°СЏ РїСЂРѕС†РµРґСѓСЂР°.

        (untitled2.exe:6904): GStreamer-WARNING **: 02:29:33.475: Failed to load plugin 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstwebrtcdsp.dll': 'E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstwebrtcdsp.dll': 
The specified procedure was not found.
        0:00:00.107822720  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                 filesrc gstfilesrc.c:533:gst_file_src_start:<source> error: No such file "C:\Users\Shmeisser\Documents\build-untitled2-Desktop_Qt_5_9_4_MinGW_32bit-Debug\ autovideosrc ! videoconvert ! appsink0"
        0:00:00.107911655  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3469:gst_base_src_start:<source> error: Failed to start
        0:00:00.108341459  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                 filesrc gstfilesrc.c:533:gst_file_src_start:<source> error: No such file "C:\Users\Shmeisser\Documents\build-untitled2-Desktop_Qt_5_9_4_MinGW_32bit-Debug\ autovideosrc ! videoconvert ! appsink0"
        0:00:00.108391029  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3469:gst_base_src_start:<source> error: Failed to start
        0:00:00.108489004  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                 filesrc gstfilesrc.c:533:gst_file_src_start:<source> error: No such file "C:\Users\Shmeisser\Documents\build-untitled2-Desktop_Qt_5_9_4_MinGW_32bit-Debug\ autovideosrc ! videoconvert ! appsink0"
        0:00:00.108535367  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3469:gst_base_src_start:<source> error: Failed to start
        0:00:00.108575898  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3824:gst_base_src_activate_push:<source> Failed to start in push mode
        0:00:00.108603015  6904   1F44A7C0 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:1142:gst_pad_set_active:<source:src> Failed to activate pad
```

Comment: How did you build/install GStreamer? Before adding the complexity of building OpenCV with GStreamer support and integrating with it, can you even successfully just test GStreamer via the `gst-launch-1.0.exe` utility from the command line? Anyway, your error is complaining about failing to load plugins. Did you also build/install any of the various good/bad/ugly plugin sets?

Comment: @rob3c I installed gstreamer and gstreamer-devel for mingw32 from official site. During the installation i chose all packages, so i installed everything i can. Yes, all pipelines which i can't run with opencv succsesfully work with gst-launch-1.0.exe

Comment: Is that lib folder on your path? Where is `libstdc++-6.dll` on your system? What happens if you copy it to where those failing libs are? A dll will fail to load if it or any of its dependencies fails to load.  In regular windows, you can use `gflags.exe` or the equivalent registry settings to debug library load failures, but I’m not sure what happens with gflags under mingw.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, but a lot of space for mistakes. The Gstreamer pipe works. The extended description is available here [Tutorial](https://funvision.blogspot.com/2020/03/compile-opencv-4-for-visual-studio-2019.html).

[image: Gstreamer result]

I used3)
- OpenCV source opencv-4.2.0
- OpenCV source opencv_contrib-4.2.0
- Cmake 3.17 release candidate 3, This is important. 
I used development and runtime installer for MSVC GStreamer
Gstreamer 1.16.2 runtime installer
Gstreamer 1.16.2 development installer
[image: what to download]
The following steps are common for OpenCV to build from source and OpenCV installation. Additionally, these resources needs to be added during cmake configuration.
[image: Gstreamer Cmake opencv config]

Now build OpenCV project generated by CMAKE in Visual Studio 2019. The last important thing is to set environmental variables to find GStreamer Runtime. Into system variable path: add

- xxx\1.0\x86_64\bin
- xxx\1.0\x86_64\lib
- xxx\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0
  [image: Environmental variables]

Comment: in my question i wrote about mingw. there is no any trouble to build opencv + gstreamer with msvc on windows